# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'defaults'

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

i made a function appendScript which will be called on a button click event my function code is

```
function appendScript() {
    var v_js;
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    v_js = document.createElement('script');
    v_js.type = 'text/javascript';
    v_js.src = "/resource/1372205606000/jquery_min_js";
    head.appendChild(v_js);
    interval = self.setInterval(function () {
        if (jQuery) {
            window.clearInterval(interval);

            var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
            v_js = document.createElement('script');
            v_js.type = "text/javascript";

            v_js.src = "/resource/1372176744000/bootstrap_min_js";
        }
        body.appendChild(v_js);
        var v_css = document.createElement('link');
        v_css.rel = "stylesheets";
        v_css.type = "text/css";
        v_css.href = "/resource/1372206945000/bootstrap_min_css";
        body.appendChild(v_css);
    }, 300);

    var interval1 = self.setInterval(function () {

        if (typeof (jQuery.fn.modal) !== 'undefined') {
            console.log('Hello!!');
            window.clearInterval(interval1);
            jQuery(document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).append('<div id="myModal"  class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"   aria-hidden="true"><div class="modal-header"><button type="button" class="close"  data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button><h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3></div><div class="modal-body"><p>One fine body…</p></div><div  class="modal-footer"><button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button><button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button></div></div>');
            var bootstrapModal = $.fn.modal.noConflict(); // return $.fn.button to previously assigned value
            $.fn.bootstrapModal = bootstrapModal;
            $('#myModal').bootstrapModal('show');
        }
    }, 300);
}
```

and the error i am facing is

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'defaults' of undefined bootstrap_min_js:6
(anonymous function) bootstrap_min_js:6
x.extend.each jquery_min_js:4
x.fn.x.each jquery_min_js:4
e.fn.modal bootstrap_min_js:6
(anonymous function)
```

Answer (score 1):

`modal.noConflict` returns a reference to the `modal` function and reverts `$.fn.modal` to whatever it was *before* the modal plugin was loaded.

However, that newly defined `modal` function actually makes use of `$.fn.modal.defaults`.  Googling reveals that this is an [unresolved and closed bug](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/6458).

The simplest solution is probably to *not* call `noConflict`, since as revealed by your exception, `$.fn.modal` is not defined and likely not conflicting with anything.

Another solution, as @fat suggests in a comment on the linked bug, would be to use jquery-ui's `bridge` function.